# Accessing Ruby class methods with io console

Tags: ruby, class, io

I'm creating a simple task manager in Ruby and am having trouble running a class method on an object that I've created.  Here's my backend code:

```
class TM::Project
  attr_accessor :name, :pid, :tasks
  @@projects = []

  def initialize(name=nil)
    @name = name
    @pid = @@projects.size
    @tasks = []
    @@projects << self
  end

  def add_task(priority, description)
    task = TM::Task.new(priority, description)
    @tasks << task
  end
end

class TM::Task
  attr_accessor :tid, :description, :priority, :status, :creation_date
  @@tasks = []

  def initialize(priority, description)
    @description = description
    @priority = priority
    @tid = @@tasks.size
    @@tasks << self
    @status = "incomplete"
    @creation_date = Time.now
  end
end
```

And here's the code for the console:

```
require_relative 'lib/task-manager.rb'

class Task_io
  @@io_projects = []

  def start
    puts "Welcome to Task Manager.  How may we assist you?\n\n"

    puts "Available Commands: \n"
    puts "  create NAME - Create a new project with name=NAME"
    puts "  add PID PRIORITY DESC - Add a new task to project with id=PID"

    puts 'Enter request>'
    req = gets.chomp
    input = req.split

    if input[0] == 'create'
        proj = TM::Project.new(input[1])
        puts "#{proj.name} was created with ID=#{proj.pid}"
        @@io_projects << proj
        self.start
    elsif input[0] == 'add'
        i = 0
        proj_id = input[1].to_i
        @@io_projects[proj_id].add_task(input[2], input[3].to_s)
        puts "#{input[3].to_s} was assigned TID #{@@tasks[i + 1]}"
        i += 1
        self.start
    else
      puts "Invalid request, please try again"
      self.start
    end
  end
end
```

I'm able to create projects, but when I try to add a task to the project I get the following error:

```
undefined method `add_task' for nil:NilClass
```

Am I accessing the object incorrectly?

Comment: You're accessing the nil object.  You create @@projects in Task_io as an empty array, and never populate it with anything.

Comment: Also, don't confuse @@projects defined in class TM::Project with @@projects defined in class Task_io.  They are not the same thing as each other.

Comment: I edited to show where I add the project to the empty array, but I'm still getting the same error.  As I understand it, I'm pushing the object into the Task_io array and should be able to run the method on that object.  Is that right, or do I need to access @@projects within the TM::Project class?

Comment: I would try to verify that @@io_projects contains anything, and that input[1].to_i is also valid.  Also, having start recursively call itself that way is not a great idea.  A loop with a quit condition would be better.

Comment: It looks like @@io_projects is indeed empty.  Do you know why that would be?  I had used this technique before refactoring the backend code (mostly updating the way that IDs were captured) and it worked, so I'm struggling to figure out what I changed that would have broken this method.

Comment: Ack, I think I figured it out - it's now listing projects as long as the @@io_projects array is outside of the start method.  I was reinitializing with an empty class every time new info was entered.  Thanks for helping me think through this!